# Why the <stack> include doesn't work on mac command line tools?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, stack

The code below works fine on Windows, but when I compile it on Mac's Xcode, I don't get any output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   stack<int> S;
   S.push(5);
   cout << S.top();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Using `<< flush` doesn't work either so I don't think this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @tuple_cat - Maybe I'm missing something, but the only thing I can see wrong with this code is the lack of newline/flush.

Comment: Adding a `<< '\n'` (or `<< endl`) does work, but flushing has no effect. I don't think the problem is with the code (AFAIK the C++ streams should be flushed automatically when the program exits), but rather with Xcode (this works fine when run in Terminal).

Comment: Did you try without the stack? Did it make a difference?

Comment: @tuple_cat - So it's possible that there's something funky with the IDE, but note that that question has more than one answer :)

Comment: Yeah maybe Xcode's console is just line-buffered.

Comment: Adding a new line resolves the problem, so thank you all.